# VBA Sort Rows into Different Worksheets Based on Array of Strings

Tags: vba, excel

Beginner VBA scripter here. How can I fix my code so that it will search thru Sheet1 for the string array in strSearch and copy those rows into Sheet2?

Also, how can I extend the code to be able to search for a different string array and copy it into another worksheet?

```
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1
      .AutoFilterMode = False
      lRow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      With .Range("J1:J" & lRow)
      On Error Resume Next
      strSearch = Array("John","Jim")
      .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strSearch
      Set copyFrom = .Offset(0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
      On Error GoTo 0
   End With

   Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
   With ws2
      On Error Resume Next
      lastRow = ws2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
      Set Rng = copyFrom.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
      Rng.Copy .Cells(lastRow + 1, "C")
      copyFrom.Delete
      On Error GoTo 0
   End With
   .AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the lines and the array:

```
Option Explicit

Dim firstRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs1 As Long
Dim lastRowWs2 As Long
Dim searchColumnWs1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim check As Variant
Dim strSearch As Variant

Sub test()
    lastRowWs1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastRowWs2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    firstRowWs1 = 2
    searchColumnWs1 = 1
    strSearch = Array("John", "Jim")

    For i = firstRowWs1 To lastRowWs1
        For Each check In strSearch
            If check = ws1.Cells(i, searchColumnWs1).Value Then
                ws1.Rows(i).Copy (ws2.Rows(lastRowWs2 + 1))
                lastRowWs2 = lastRowWs2 + 1
                ws1.Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
                i = i - 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next check
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: I set the (Name) - Property of the tables to "ws1" and "ws2"

Comment: Is it possible to copy the row to start at column C instead of column A on ws2?

Comment: As far is I know not. To accomplish that you have to work with ranges. Define the first and the last column of the range in that row where you copy from. Define it also where you want to copy to. If the range is the same size than you can copy it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strsearchlocation as integer    
strSearchLocation = Sheet1.Cells.Find(what:= strSearch, After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row    
Sheet1.Rows(strSearchLocation).Copy
```

Finds and copies the row of strSearch

Comment: I am getting a syntax error on the second line. When I try to add the code it says: "Expected list separator or )" and highlights the colon after the "what"

Comment: There should have been an = after the :

My bad